# How do I start Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I installed Minecraft 1.7.2 and after installation it showed the launcher, and I played the game successfully.

But after I closed it, I realised there's no shortcut for Minecraft on the desktop, and when I go to my .minecraft folder and try to run anything there (such as `launcher.jar`, or `1.7.2.jar`) nothing will open and nothing happens.

How do I start Minecraft?

Comment: What did you use to install it? For example, in windows, you can download (or used to be able to download) just the .exe file and put wherever you want. Haven't installed it since ~1.4 or so, just use update feature.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if your minecraft launcher is in the same place, but my shortcut leads to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe
```

And if it matters, I'm on a Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the correct method, it should be located at:

> "%AppData%\.minecraft\minecraft launcher\Minecraft Launcher.exe"

It is also possible you have a custom installer which points it to a different location. To find this, you can easily search for "minecraft" in your start bar, right click and "Open File Location".

If this satisfies your question, please mark it so.